# How to get receipt gasUsed in string?

Tags: gas, ethers.js, gas-price

I'm using ethers.js and I do remember using `console.log(Gas used: ${receipt.gasUsed.toString()})` before and I could get the `gasUsed` in string. But now it's returning the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')`

Any other option to get it in string?

```
      const sendToken = await signer.sendTransaction(tx);

      await sendToken.wait();
      console.log(`Transaction successful with hash: ${sendToken.hash}`);

      const receipt = await provider.getTransaction(sendToken.hash);

      console.log(`Transaction confirmed in block ${receipt.blockNumber}`);
      console.log(`Gas used: ${receipt.gasUsed.toString()}`);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/

Looking at the documentation for ethers we can see that getTransaction does not contain the field gasUsed.
[image]

However, searching for gasUsed in the documentation we will see that it does infact exists as you thought but not under getTransaction.

[image]

You should be able to access gasUsed by replacing it with getTransactionReceipt instead.

Hope it helped!

Comment: Excellent. It worked. I had a hard time understanding the doc, thanks for making it easier.

Comment: No problem, glad it worked for you!